# jquery .get page load not loading at top of page

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

Right now I have a script that when you click a button its content is dynamically loaded into a content container and it is not loading at it's top (loads at same height down as you scrolled on last dynamically loaded page). I tried putting in scrollTop and all the other fixes I could see online, but nothing seems to work for this.

**Here is the jquery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.load-page', function(){

    var href = $(this).attr("data-href");

    $.get(href,function (hdisplayed) {
        $("#content").html( hdisplayed ).scrollTop(0);
    });
});
```

I tried putting .scrollTop() everywhere I could think of with it not working. If you think you know how to put it in that would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**Edit: Here is the HTML as requested**

```
<li data-href="home.html" class="load-page"></li>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: And could you please provide the related HTML with CSS stylesheets?

Comment: a demo displaying the issue would help. Maybe you want to reset `body` scrolltop?

Comment: Is your container scrollable or only the page?

Comment: yeah the container is scrollable

Comment: I am kinda new to jquery and feel I have been trying to put .scrollTop just in improper places. I would have thought adding it to the end of a chain would move it to top once everything prior was finished. Also I am not sure how to make it work in a code pen as I need other pages loading in with just lots of lorem text content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the following to your function:

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

This will utilize the scrollTop and reset it to 0 status. It targets the window upon every time your load page function runs. It should work.

```
// loads pages
        $(document).on('click', '.load-page', function(){
        var href = $(this).attr("data-href");

        $.get(href,function (hdisplayed) {
            $("#content").html( hdisplayed );
   $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });
    });
```

Comment: this worked thanks, i never tried using window. surprised this isnt a big issue that everyone knows about.